# fancyhdr: how to get head ruler on pages where a chapter starts?

Tags: fancyhdr

I am using the fancyplain page style, and still headers on pages where a chapter starts look different from headers on pages where no new chapter starts.

On normal pages, fancyhdr adds a horizontal line below the header. On pages where a new chapter starts, it does not. Does anyone know how to add this line on such pages?

Comment: Please always add a MWE.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I didn't note that this was for `fancyheadings` package. However, if you look in the package documentation, you'll find that the width of the header's rule in `plain` pages is set through the command `\plainheadrulewidth`. **However**, if you try to run a code with the `fancyheadings` package, you'll get this message:

```
Package fancyheadings Warning: Please stop using fancyheadings!
(fancyheadings) Use fancyhdr instead.
(fancyheadings) We will call fancyhdr with the very same
(fancyheadings) options you passed to fancyheadings.
```

Therefore, I'd suggest you to follow this advice and convert to `fancyhdr` :-) !

**Answer:**

You don't see a line because the first page of each chapter is by default in `plain` style. To have a header in these pages too, you have to redefine this style:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% Redefine the PLAIN style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhead{} %Clean headers
    \fancyfoot{} %Clean footers
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt} % Header rule's width
}
% Define the DEFAULT style
\fancypagestyle{MyStyle}{%
    \fancyhead{} %Clean headers
    \fancyfoot{} %Clean footers
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt} % Header rule's width
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{MyStyle}

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

However, take into account that this will change *all* your `plain` pages, such as the first page of Table of Contents, and so on.