# How to suppress the page number on the first page of the chapter

Tags: fancyhdr, geometry

I need to suppress the page number on the first page of the chapter. I read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74488/fancyheaders-how-to-turn-off-the-page-number-on-the-first-page) and used their advice. It does its job. But fancyhdr inserts the header and footer line in the 'contents' page.

If I remove the recommended line 
`\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}}` after `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` the header and footer lines disappear on the content page, but the page number appears on the Chapter page. I do not understand why. 
MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{euler,beton}


\usepackage[paperwidth=145mm, paperheight=215mm,inner=1.6cm,top=2.4cm,bottom=4cm,textwidth=7.4cm,marginparwidth=40mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\fancypagestyle{style1}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
}
\fancypagestyle{style2}{
\fancyhf{}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
}
\fancypagestyle{style3}{
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
}

\author{A. Uthor}
\title{What is the Title of This Book?}
\date{today}


\begin{document}

\newgeometry{top=24mm,bottom=40mm,inner=16mm,outer=3.2cm}
\pagestyle{style1}
\maketitle


\thispagestyle{empty}
{This page is intentionally left blank}

\newgeometry{top=24mm,bottom=40mm,inner=16mm,outer=3.2cm,marginparwidth=20mm}
\pagestyle{style2}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}


\section*{Intro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{Intro}}

\lipsum

\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}



\newgeometry{inner=1.6cm,top=2.4cm,bottom=4cm,textwidth=7.4cm,marginparwidth=40mm}

\pagestyle{style3}
\chapter{The First Chapter}
\section{Section about everything}
\lipsum[1-2]\marginpar{\lipsum[1]}\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Output: 
[image]

My goal is to have different styles for the introduction and for the main part (wider margins for graffiti.

**Contents** preferably with page number (as they are now), but absolutely no rulers.

**Introduction**: rulers

**Chapter**: Absolutely blank first page. The text is narrower, no rulers. The following pages are with rulers and same (narrow) width of the text.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I added these two lines to style 3, and i think it did the job:

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %<- ADDED
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} %<- ADDED
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{euler,beton}


\usepackage[paperwidth=145mm, paperheight=215mm,inner=1.6cm,top=2.4cm,bottom=4cm,textwidth=7.4cm,marginparwidth=40mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\fancypagestyle{style1}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
}
\fancypagestyle{style2}{
\fancyhf{}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
}
\fancypagestyle{style3}{
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %<- ADDED
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} %<- ADDED
}

\author{A. Uthor}
\title{What is the Title of This Book?}
\date{today}


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{style1}
\maketitle

\newgeometry{top=24mm,bottom=40mm,inner=16mm,outer=3.2cm}
\thispagestyle{empty}
{This page is intentionally left blank}


\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\newgeometry{top=24mm,bottom=40mm,inner=16mm,outer=3.2cm,marginparwidth=20mm}
\pagestyle{style2}
\section*{Intro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{Intro}}

\lipsum

\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}



\newgeometry{inner=1.6cm,top=2.4cm,bottom=4cm,textwidth=7.4cm,marginparwidth=40mm}

\pagestyle{style3}
\chapter{The First Chapter}
\section{Section about anything}
\lipsum[1-2]\marginpar{\lipsum[1]}\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

output:
 [image]

**EDIT::**

If you want to empty style for the first page of the chapter you can add

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

after the chapter exactly.

following is the new output:

[image]

The New Code:

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{book}%

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{euler,beton}


    \usepackage[paperwidth=145mm, paperheight=215mm,inner=1.6cm,top=2.4cm,bottom=4cm,textwidth=7.4cm,marginparwidth=40mm]{geometry}

    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}}
    \pagestyle{fancy}

    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

    \fancypagestyle{style1}{
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
        \fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
        \fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
    }
    \fancypagestyle{style2}{
        \fancyhf{}
        \addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}
        \addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
        \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
        \fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
        \fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
    }
    \fancypagestyle{style3}{
        \fancyhf{}
        \setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
        \addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}
        \addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
        \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
        \fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
        \fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
    %   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %<- ADDED
    %   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} %<- ADDED
    }

    \author{A. Uthor}
    \title{What is the Title of This Book?}
    \date{today}


    \begin{document}

        \pagestyle{style1}
        \maketitle

        \newgeometry{top=24mm,bottom=40mm,inner=16mm,outer=3.2cm}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        {This page is intentionally left blank}


        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \tableofcontents
        \clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

        \newgeometry{top=24mm,bottom=40mm,inner=16mm,outer=3.2cm,marginparwidth=20mm}
        \pagestyle{style2}
        \section*{Intro}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{Intro}}

        \lipsum

        \clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}



        \newgeometry{inner=1.6cm,top=2.4cm,bottom=4cm,textwidth=7.4cm,marginparwidth=40mm}

        \pagestyle{style3}
        \chapter{The First Chapter}
            \thispagestyle{empty} %<-- ADDED
        \section{Section about anything}
        \lipsum[1-2]\marginpar{\lipsum[1]}\lipsum[1-5]

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I cannot accept it as the answer since it gets rid of the rulers on the following pages. To keep them is another problem as I don't understand how and where to change the style back. So more new questions than answers. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I edited the solution to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the answer to the question but took into consideration that the reader also wants to know what page the chapter starts (for search and for navigation), so I ended up with the following.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{euler,beton}


\usepackage[paperwidth=145mm, paperheight=215mm,inner=1.6cm,top=2.4cm,bottom=4cm,textwidth=7.4cm,marginparwidth=40mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\fancypagestyle{style1}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
}
\fancypagestyle{style2}{
\fancyhf{}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
}
\fancypagestyle{style3}{
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
}

% Redefine the PLAIN style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhead{} %Clean headers
    \fancyfoot{} %Clean footers
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt} % Header rule's width
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
}
% Define the DEFAULT style
\fancypagestyle{MyStyle}{%
    \fancyhead{} %Clean headers
    \fancyfoot{} %Clean footers
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt} % Header rule's width
        \setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
        \addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}
        \addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
}

\author{A. Uthor}
\title{What is the Title of This Book?}
\date{today}


\begin{document}

\newgeometry{top=24mm,bottom=40mm,inner=16mm,outer=3.2cm}
\pagestyle{style1}
\maketitle


\thispagestyle{empty}
{This page is intentionally left blank}

\newgeometry{top=24mm,bottom=40mm,inner=16mm,outer=3.2cm,marginparwidth=20mm}
\pagestyle{style2}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}


\section*{Intro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{Intro}}

\lipsum

\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}



\newgeometry{inner=1.6cm,top=2.4cm,bottom=4cm,textwidth=7.4cm,marginparwidth=40mm}

\pagestyle{MyStyle}
\chapter{The First Chapter}
\section{Section about everything}
\lipsum[1-2]\marginpar{\lipsum[1]}\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[This link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263133/fancyhdr-how-to-get-head-ruler-on-pages-where-a-chapter-starts) helped. This MWE has [another follow up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404049/wrong-header-text).

Comment: I edited the solution to meet your requirements.